# Dynamically adding generic services from one concrete implementation using Castle Windsor

Tags: .net, castle-windsor

I'm using Castle Windsor, and I've got the following:

```
public class NhibernateRepository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public NHibernateRepository(...)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

I'd like to use the Fluent Windsor API To register one service for each of my domain models

That is, I would like to dynamically register `IRepository<Order>`, `IRepository<Customer>`, `IRepository<Article>` etc using `NHibernateRepository<T>` where `T` is then exchanged for the concrete type in each instance.

I've got something like this:

```
container.Register(AllTypes.FromThisAssembly().Where(x => x.Namespace == "DITest.Repository").WithService.Select(...Something...)
```

But I'm not sure if this can even be done (AllTypes does after all imply that I want to register multiple types).

Any Windsor Guru out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial with Windsor:

```
container.Register(Component.For(typeof(IRepository<>))
          .ImplementedBy(typeof(NHibernateRepository<>)))
```

Windsor will automagically close the generic types with any given type argument.

Note that the non-generic overloads of `For` and `ImplementedBy` are used only because of a language limitation - it is not valid C# to specify open generic types as types arguments (i.e. `For<IRepository<>>` would not compile).

More info on [the official documentation wiki](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx?HL=type,generic#To_register_a_generic_type_2).

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know it was possible to specify empty type argument lists. Very compact and readable :)